# I want to make card in react using realtime-database json

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase and react, my realtime database have items like this:

```
items
--> i1
--> --> img:   "google-logo.jpg"
--> --> title:   "google"
--> --> subtitle:   "go to google"
--> --> url:   "https://google.com"
--> i2
--> --> img:   "facebook-logo.jpg"
--> --> title:   "facebook"
--> --> subtitle:   "go to facebook"
--> --> url:   "https://facebook.com"
--> i3
--> --> img:   "jpg3"
--> --> title:   "twitter"
--> --> subtitle:   "go to twitter"
--> --> url:   "https://twitter.com"
```

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get("https://~~~firebase url~~~/items.json")
    .then(response => setPosts(response.data));
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          {JSON.stringify(posts)}
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can get json from firebase and show it on browser, I want to make reusable cards that have img, title. And if user click that card, it'll send user to that url.

Is there any good way to make card components using that JSON?

Comment: **1.** Your code is incomplete. **2.** Can you share the JSON too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your functional component create the card component as follows:

```
const Card = (props) => (
    <div className="card">
        <a href={props.data.url}><h5 className="card-header">{props.data.title}</h5></a>
        <div className="card-body">
            <h4 className="card-title"></h4>
            <p className="card-text">
            </p>
        </div >
    </div >
)
```

Then inside your functional component create one function to send data through props:

```
cardData() {
        return posts.map((info, i) => {
            return <Card data={info} key={i} />;
        })
    }
```

Then inside your `<div className="App">` whereever you want to set your card elements write {cardData()}.

You can customize the cards as per your requirement just have a look at bootstrap cards.

Comment: I got some error

Comment: As I am new contributor I am unable to comment on below post that's why I am answering here. Have a look at bootstrap cards from this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/                                              
You can choose different cards as per your requirement. You can also use reactstrap cards : https://reactstrap.github.io/components/card/

Comment: @lsr Now you can.

Answer (score 0):

yeah it works, thank you so much
Is there any good example to styled that cards??

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Card = (props) => {
  return (  
    <div className="card">
      <a href={props.data.url}><h5 className="card-header">{props.data.title}</h5></a>
      <img className="image" src={props.data.img} alt="alt message"></img>
      <div className="card-body">
        <h4 className="card-title">{props.data.title}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function cardData(posts) {
  var values = Object.values(posts);
  return values.map((info, idx) => {
    return <Card data={info} key={idx} />;
  })
}

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get("https://~~~~~~~~~`/items.json")
    .then(response => setPosts(response.data));
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {JSON.stringify(posts)}
      {cardData(posts)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```